# Installing Java 3D onto Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-3d, bin

I have already set my variable paths to include the bin and lib file for j3d. When I open eclipse, I have to manually build path->configure build path->add jars and add all the .jar files for every project. Then I have to set their native paths to the .bin folder. It's a very tedious process. I was wondering if there is a way where I can install j3D into my eclipse so all the libraries are already added to all projects.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if you have tried this or it seems obvious, but perhaps you could use a library management tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) or ANT (which comes with Eclipse).

These tools allow you to include all necessary libraries for a bulid into a pom.xml file.  And then ANT/Maven software does all the tedious including for you during the build process.  The tools have a bit of overhead involved, but there are plenty of [tutorials](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html) out there to help you learn them.  We typically use Maven in all of our larger Eclipse projects.

Comment: Maven is a good choice. Especially usefull when deploying app with Java3D libraries. Otherwise it have to be done manually and it is not a pleasant task.

Answer (score 1):

You create user library which contains all the necessary jars. Then you can use this library in any project. To use it in another eclipse workspace, just export it.

You can find user libraries in `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Build Path` -> `User Libraries`.